# Get the output of a shell Command in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, shell

I have a VB.net program in which I call the Shell function. I would like to get the text output that is produced from this code in a file. However, this is not the return value of the executed code so I don't really know how to.

This program is a service but has access to the disk no problem as I already log other information. The whole service has multiple threads so I must also make sure that when the file is written it's not already accessed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You won't be able to capture the output from Shell.

You will need to change this to a process and you will need to capture the the [Standard Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx#Y1596) (and possibly Error) streams from the process.

Here is an example:

```
        Dim oProcess As New Process()
        Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ApplicationName.exe", "arguments")
        oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
        oProcess.Start()

        Dim sOutput As String
        Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
            sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine(sOutput)
```

To get the standard error:

```
'Add this next to standard output redirect
 oStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True

'Add this below
Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = checkOut.StandardError
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Comment: @DT, the link supplied in your comment is no longer valid - do you know of any other confirmations for this behavior?

Comment: but the code still works...

Answer (score 12):

Just pipe the output to a text file?

```
MyCommand > "c:\file.txt"
```

Then read the file.

Comment: Actually, I did found out the solution last night before reading this and it's quite close. I will use >> instead because I want to append the results each time, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I forgot to mention you should consider `MyCommand > "c:\file.txt 2>&1` if you also want to capture *error* reports in the file. By default error outputs are not included in the file.

Comment: @mark : i'm not the downvoter, but i can explain : i hate having to use "save-to-file" "read-file". It's slow, bad and uggly

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim proc As New Process

    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\ipconfig.bat"   
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.Start()
    proc.WaitForExit()

    Dim output() As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar(vbLf))
    For Each ln As String In output
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(ln & vbNewLine)
        lstScan.Items.Add(ln & vbNewLine)
    Next
```

=======================================================================
create a batch file in two lines as shown below:

```
    echo off
    ipconfig
```

' make sure you save this batch file as ipconfig.bat or whatever name u decide to pick but make sure u put dot bat at the end of it.

Comment: Part of your code snipet has slipped out of the code box

Comment: Naming the batch file after an existing command will result in an endless loop. I leanrt it a hard way :-)