# How to Copy CMD Results into Textbox on VB.Net Project

Tags: vb.net, cmd, command

I'm working on a Project by VB.net and i'm using CMD to excute commands i want to Know how to copy the Results of the CMD into a textbox on my Main Form

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the output of a shell Command in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the accepted answer here: [Get the output of a shell Command in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net). That is probably what you need.

Also, here is a version of the code that puts the result into the textbox:

```
        Dim oProcess As New Process()
        Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ApplicationName.exe", "arguments")
        oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
        oProcess.Start()

        Dim sOutput As String
        Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
            sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using

        txtOutput.Text = sOutput   'txtOutput being the output textbox.
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

```
    Dim proc As New Process

    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\ipconfig.bat"   
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.Start()
    proc.WaitForExit()

    Dim output() As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar(vbLf))
    For Each ln As String In output
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(ln & vbNewLine)
        lstScan.Items.Add(ln & vbNewLine)
    Next
```

'Created a file in batch with 2 lines as shown below:

echo off
ipconfig

' save this file as ipconfig.bat or whatever name u want. 
' if you didn't want that you could use any command on there like this:

echo off
dir/s

or

echo off
cd\
dir/s
pause