# How to get multi shell command output

Tags: vb.net

How to get multi shell command output to textbox or listbox in vb.net:

```
shell("""adb/adb.exe"" shell "" getprop ro.product.name""" ,AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, 30000)

shell("""adb/adb.exe"" shell "" getprop ro.product.version.release""" ,AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, 30000)

shell("""adb/adb.exe"" shell "" getprop ro.product.version.sdk""" ,AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, 30000)
```

Sorry for spelling.
Thank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the output of a shell Command in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net , can't get multi output ,it only work one command ,Thank.