# How to Apply Parallelism in VB.NET to execute 130 batch files Saved in one folder?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have 130 batch files stored in one central location, I want to create VB.NET program to execute those batch files in parallel NOT in sequence. and then return the output of these 130 batch files to Textbox control.

How can I cater the above requirements? or what's the recommended way of doing it, keeping in mind the program will run on a high Specs Server so performance is not an issue here.

What I have done is I placed this for loop inside Button_Click Event to get my .bat names & then to get them executed in parallel:

```vb
    Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Batch\")
    Dim fileName As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.bat")
    For Each file As IO.FileInfo In fileName
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(file.ToString() & vbNewLine)
    Next
```

But now here after i got the names of .dat, how to get them executed in parallel?

Comment: It makes no sense to parallelize, because all rests in the speed of reading from the hard/solid drive.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, I think that would depend on the batch files. If they also fetch some data or something else that they have to wait for then parallel execution does make sense.

Comment: @RonDeijkers - Agree. Waiting for clarification from the author.

Comment: @RonDeijkers you're right, the batch files will fetch some data from certain location, for that i need to execute it in parallel not to wait for the first job & move on to the next one.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov The batch files will fetch some data from certain location, for that i need to execute it in parallel not to wait for the first job & move on to the next one

Comment: Gave a Google at **parallel.for**.  Bear in mind that you shouldn't try to add the results to the textbox till the loop has finished,  so you'll need to add them to a string/list of string first.

Comment: @DavidWilson, can you please help me in implementing it as a high level, since am new to it

Comment: I'd be more than happy to have a go,  but I don't really have enough free time till next weekend.  If I do get some time,  I'll certainly have a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I could get, combining the comments and the updated description

```vb
Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Batch\")
Dim fileName As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.bat")
Dim list As New List(Of String)
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In fileName
    list.Add(file.ToString())
Next

Dim processTasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))()

    For Each bat As String In list
        Dim processTask As Task(Of String) = Task.Factory.StartNew((Function()
                                             Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(myDirectory.FullName, bat) 
                                             Dim info As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
                                             info.FileName = filePath
                                             info.CreateNoWindow = True
                                             info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                                             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info)
                                             Return "hello"
                                             End Function))

        processTasks.Add(processTask)
    Next

' if you are using a synchronous method
' Dim results() As String = Task.WhenAll(processTasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
' if you are using an async method
Dim results() As String = await Task.WhenAll(processTasks)

' Either use the string array as a whole, or
For Each result As String In results
    ' Do something with every individual result
Next
```

Comment: I have run the above code, but it end up in the following error: An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Omran check again, had forgotten to add the path to the folder

Comment: @cFtozenDeath - now am getting this error An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: @Omran are you sure you are using the exact same code? Check that "list" does not contain any illegal character, like / ^ & etc

Comment: now it works fine, but here i want to keep all cmd windows hidden & result should be sent to textbox, can it be done?

Comment: how about redirecting the output of these .bat files to Textbox? :)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov - it's just showing me the last line of batch file which is Press any key to continue . . ., i want to get the full output??

Comment: @Omran please mark this as solved, as getting the full output has nothing to do with the original question. However, please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net

Comment: it's just showing me the last line of batch file which is Press any key to continue . . ., i want to get the full output??

Comment: @ cFrozenDeath Thanks a lot of the help :) & sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer your answer is in C#, which is ok, but the OP prefers VB.NET. Not only this, but you provide barely NO information about how to use the tasks, and the for loop is very weird. Your answer could only work as a base for someone experienced in tasks.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I don't see any explanation about `Task`, in the other hand OP tagged the whole question with [c#], and finally, we couldn't know how OP was going to provide how to loop over 130 batch files, I believe my answer was enough for any further reader to understand the approach.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath BTW, I'm that kind of people that avoid providing full solutions, but a guide to let the OP understand him/herself how to solve the issue. Anyway, I still think that your answer is a copy-paste solution from mine. If the OP felt that this is better, why not, we're here to solve issue an contribute with quality content.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer a copy paste would have been a copy paste. My answer is not in the same language as yours, and my answer gives insight on how to process the files inside the task. Yours do absolutely nothing but create 130 tasks and await for hem to complete without even taking into account what the tasks returned

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Now I'm going to give you an idea to demonstrate that it's not a copy-pasted answer, but **why the variable names are identical in both answers?**. In the other hand, you've downgraded my solution with `Task.Factory.StartNew` while `Task.Run` uses the thread pool? Also, OP asked about *how to parallelize*, not about how to work with I/O in .NET which I supose that OP knew already before asking this question.....

Comment: @cFrozenDeath About the language, there're many language translators out there, and changing the language doesn't change the point of a copy-pasted answer. You took my code, you changed it to VB.NET either automatically or manually, and you added the part of `Process`, which I guess OP knew already too...

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Anyway I'm not here to get points, I don't care the points, it's just I feel you provided zero background in your answer: you copy-pasted my approach and translated it to VB.NET 2 hours later after I've added my answer........ it seems like a bad habit here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath In fact, I would argue that there's another approach: `Parallel.For` but you decided to explain the same providing a VB sample..... well, good luck!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer this is my last comment, as SO is complaining about length. First of all, I used your answer **as reference** that's why the names. I made the translation manually, looking how to do it manually. If you **care** to read ALL the comments, you will see I've been editing the answer providing answers to the OP as he asked. He did **NOT** know how to work with your answer, and so I helped him. You comment too much BS for not caring...

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I've provided many answers to many Q&A where other contributors have explained that "gaps" in comments instead of copying the approach in another answer to almost say the same thing :D

Answer (score 0):

*Note I've answered the question using C# because OP tagged the question with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)*.

You should simply use `Task`:

```
List<Task<string>> processTasks = new List<Task<string>>();

for(int i = 0; i < 130; i ++)
{
        Task<string> processTask = Task<string>
        (
            () => 
            {
                 // System.Diagnostics.Process stuff goes here, you should return a string
                 // since it represents the output of the whole process
            }
        );

        processTasks.Add(processTask);
        Task.Run(processTask);
}

// Asynchronously wait for all tasks to finish
await Task.WhenAll(processTasks);

// Now after all tasks have finished, each stored task in "processTasks" 
// will contain a task where their "Result" property is the string representing
// the whole process output
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply, however, here I have to place each batch file name inside for loop or no easy way to pick them up from central location "batch file named as numbers"? and after each task finished, how will i get my result outputted to Textbox for each executed Batch file.??

Comment: (1) Replace the for loop with whatever you need. For example a `foreach` of a list of file names. (2) I told you it in the whole answer!! Once you've awaited all `processTasks` you just need to get the results in each `Task<string>` instance using `Task<string>.Result`.

Comment: @Omran if they are literally files, why not just use the Directory class to get all file names?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, exactly i have executed the following to get all my .bat files, but am confuse where to place in the above shared code by Matias Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
        Dim fileName As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.bat")
        For Each file As IO.FileInfo In fileName
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(file.ToString() & vbNewLine)
        Next

Comment: @Omran if you don't mind editing your question and adding the code you have right now, I'll give you an answer (kinda rusty in VB.NET but will try)

Comment: @cFrozenDeath No problem, you can code in c# also, i have knowledge of both :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Do I need to import anything? when i used your code after converting it to VB.NET it's showing error under await Task.WhenAll(processTasks); and  Task.Run(processTask);

Comment: @Omran I feel you should be able to fix the issue yourself. It's just `Task` is a class of `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. About the `await` operator, why don't you check the following MSDN page? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156570.aspx

Comment: @Omran I see you've choosen the other answer which is a copy-paste of mine just changint the `for` with a `foreach`.....