# How to get real time output of a shell command?

Tags: vb.net, shell

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net/8811377#8811377) code on how to get the output of the shell:

```
Dim oProcess As New Process()
Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ApplicationName.exe", "arguments")
oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
oProcess.Start()

Dim sOutput As String
Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
    sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
Console.WriteLine(sOutput)
```

This just reports the output once the command has finished, not in real time.

Is there a way on how to get the output in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event on processes called `OutputDataReceived` which you will need to subscribe to.

This can be done using

> AddHandler

The following way will demonstrate how this is done:

```
AddHandler oProcess.OutputDataRecived, AddressOf OutputData
```

From here it will want the method, which either Visual Studio can generate for you, or you can generate. It will need the following arguements

```
Object sender, DataRecievedEventArgs e
```

In an actual method, this will look like this:

```
Private Sub OutputDataRecieved(sender As Object, e As DataRecievedEventArgs)
```

In here you can use `e.Data` to get the current line.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks! But I don't know how to implement this. Can you give me idea on where will I put this and that?

Comment: Just under where you declare your new process, add the first line, after doing so a squiggly line should be under "OutputData". From there click on quick settings and click create new method, Or you can generate the method manually using the last line of code i provided, and inside there do your Console.WriteLine()