# Pass the result of Python script to VB.net

Tags: python, vb.net

I have a python file:

```
myFile.py

def get_value(data):#pass in data as input parameter
    output = process(data)#function to process data
    return output
```

Here, `output` can be a float number or a string.
I want to call this python script from VB.NET. I searched the web and someone suggested

```
import System.Diagnostics
Process.Start("C:\python " & "myFile.py")
```

I am not sure if it is correct. Furthermore, it does not receive `output` in the python file.

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your python script is just like that your function is never called and therefore doesn't return anything.

I don't know what kind of data you plan to return, if it's simple stuff the perhaps just print it with `print(get_value(data))` in the end of the file and capture the printed lines with the VB script?

Comment: Sorry for missing information. Here, `output` can be a float number or a string.

Comment: I have no idea, I don't do VB, but check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811377/9025164) and see if it helps.