# Multiple command on console application

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a GUI for an existing application.

The application called urjtag.exe, to run and complete using cmd like

```
C:\system32>urjtag.exe
jtag> cable jtagkey
connected to libftd2xx library.
jtag> detect
some output bla bla bla
jtag> svf c:\file\test.svf
progress 1/11765(1%) 
....
progress 1/11765(100%)
progress done
jtag> quit

C:\system32>
```

So I want to make the command input into a button and display live output on appended text box.
btn1 : open jtag.exe

btn 2 : run command "cable jtagkey"
get output on the console to append textbox

btn 3 : run command "detect"
get output on the console to append textbox

etc....

I have tried this method : [Get the output of a shell Command in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net)
still not working.

Comment: *"i have try this method ... still not working"*. That's not an explanation. You need to show us EXACTLY what you did and tell us EXACTLY what happened when you did it. If what you did didn't work then you did it wrong. We can't tell what's wrong with it if you refuse to show it to us.

Comment: VB.Net is not VB6, and neither of them are VBScript. They are not the same just because they all start with *VB*, any more than a cat, a car and a carrot are all the same because they start with *ca*. Please use only the tags that are relevant to your question. Tag spamming is a quick way to collect downvotes and get your question closed, which means it will delay your getting help here.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but are you asking how to convert your console app to something like a WinForms app?